# $\left|Df(x)\hat{u}\right|=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\hat{u}$ unit vector. Is $Df(x)$ constant?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have some regular $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ which is invertible over $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can I somehow show that if for all $\hat{u}\in S^n$ and all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we get:
$$\left|Df(x)\cdot\hat{u}\right|=1$$
Then $Df(x)$ is some constant orthogonal matrix?

Comment: What is $S^n$ ?

Comment: @se2018 - presumably Ran Kin means $S^{n-1}$, the unit hypersphere (set of all unit vectors) in $\Bbb R^n$, but hasn't yet learned that the superscript in this notation is the dimension of the hypersphere as a manifold, not the dimension of the space it has been embedded in.